# Why is the svg black and white?

Tags: svg, color-profile, scribus

Someone edited my svg file and now, if I import it into Scribus 1.5.1, It is only black, all colors are gone.

[This is the commit at github](https://github.com/rubo77/freifunk-faltblatt-6-seiten/commit/9d5583c2c03b2d9dd41945a741c33485e839cc4f#diff-8e3bf71c025c7b809179761f32894dae), where the format of the svg changed.

before, It was all in color. The new version is in color, if you open it in Inkscape or even **in Browser**:  (save [this](https://github.com/rubo77/freifunk-faltblatt-6-seiten/blob/master/flyer-6-seiten_scribus1.5/ffki-logo.svg) and open in Firefox)

Only Scribus seems to loose the colors.

I did a workaround and exported it to png before importing it in my scribus project, but still, I would like to understand the problem.

Comment: The page on github is missing (update: this might be due to [github being under a ddos attack](https://status.github.com/?20150825)). This also isn't a design question, so I'm voting to close it

Comment: So where would this fit in then? It is a question about a graphical program useage

Comment: [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would likely be your best bet on a SE site, but it's not a perfect fit

Comment: I did: the git respiratory includes all versions

Comment: I think that this is certainly a design question. There's plenty of questions on this SE site about how to use different design programs.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an issue with the nested groups. If you open the newer file in Inkscape, while you can see the colors, if you click any of the objects, you'll see "Paint is undefined" in the `Fill and Stroke window.

A simple fix is to simply remove the extraneous groups.

1. Open the file in Inkscape.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select everything.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to ungroup.
4. Click one of the colored objects and verify that its fill color shows up in the `Fill and Stroke` (Ctrl+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>). If it still says "Paint is undefined" try ungrouping 1 or 2 more times.

As you might have noticed, Scribus is a little more strict about the features used in an SVG graphic. Most SVG editors have special features in SVG files in their own namespace that Scribus doesn't understand. Inkscape can "figure it out" in this case and show the correct color, but Scribus couldn't. To debug this type of thing, I usually open the SVG in Inkscape with the XML view and walk through the image. Usually the root cause is some hinky XML in the file that can usually be removed. Saving as "Plain SVG" from Inkscape can also sometimes help (but didn't work in this case).

(Tested with Scribus 1.4.5 and Inscape 0.91)